# SQL Server convert varchar hh:mm:ss to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

Is there a way to convert varchar 'hh:mm:ss' format data to time to allowing summing?

Comment: Well, this works for you? `SELECT CONVERT(TIME, '10:00:22' );`

Comment: convert to date and use DATEADD() ?

Comment: You can't sum `time` either, it's not a length of time, it's a time of day. And you are going to have problems if you go over 24h

Comment: @Charlieface, you can convert a 'hh:mm:ss' string to time, and time to seconds, and you can then sum those seconds, no? There would be no problem if it gets over a day or a month. Display format of those seconds would be up to you (or minutes, millis ...). ie: unix time  go over a day, month, years while expressed as a number.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Correct, but OP hasn't asked for that, which is why I pointed out that `time` itself doesn't sum, you would need `DATEDIFF` also, and could not cast the result back to `time` if it went over 24h (you would need to format manually)

Comment: @Charlieface, what OP wants is to convert varchar 'hh:mm:ss' to time (cast does that), and it wants a sum of 'time' which could be expressed in a common unit like seconds, milliseconds,minutes ... Converting directly back to Time is nonsense, right.

Comment: Maybe you should add some more explanation for those who can't understand what it means to sum elapsed time.

Comment: If you're wanting to store time *spans*, then store them directly as the integer value using whatever smallest division of time you need to work in is (e.g. minutes/seconds/milliseconds). These integers can then be summed directly. Leave converting that into any form of *string* to the presentation layer, that (with luck) will have a data type that represents a time span.

Comment: Seem like you shouldn't be using a `time`, and certainly not a `varchar`, but an `int`. `varchar` is just wrong, and `time` is for *point it time* values, not durations. For example `10:00:22` represents 22 seconds past 10 o'clock, *not* 10 hours 22 seconds. You don't `SUM` time of the day. Instead, store your value as something like an `int` and `1` represents the smallest accuracy you need; seems like seconds. So 10 hours 22 seconds would be `36022`. Though you could use something like a `decimal(10,3)` if you want to store milliseconds.

Comment: CSV's don't have data types, @CetinBasoz . But when you *import* the data into your database, your ETL process should be Transforming the data appropriately into the correct strongly typed data type. Or the data should be going into a staging table so that it can be transformed prior to being inserted into the production table.

Comment: @Larnu, CSV's don't have data types, right but to you they are (var)char values, no? There are real world usages like that. I believe it is just the OP didn't express it cleanly.

Comment: The OP taking a CSV file and importing it all as `varchar` values is a flaw, @CetinBasoz . It doesn't change my point in any way. In the **Database** the appropriate data types should be defined. This isn't a question about CSVs, it's about SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu, so you never got data from anywhere in some format that shouldn't be in and you never needed to make a conversion. Good for you. All of us don't live in a perfect world as you do. OP or anyone might have got data from elsewhere or imported that data maybe to a transient table for ETL processing. Simply put if you have string values of timespan (all under 24 hours) kept as string somewhere and you need total time expressed in some time unit, you can do that, first casting to a time (or datetime, datetime2 ..). It is not summing "time of day" (meaningless).

Comment: What are you talking about @CetinBasoz ... I have no idea where this CSV file you're talking about is, but it isn't in the question, and good ETL is good ETL. *Good* ETL transform that `hh:mm:ss` value to a numerical value... If you want to store all your data as a `varchar` in your database, then do so, but it's **wrong**. I suggest you take the time to fix that design.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @InX VARCHAR(10)='09:08:23'
SELECT CAST(@InX AS TIME(0))
```

Comment: Can you sum TIME values?

Comment: Can you give an example of two time values and the desired output? For example, what would you expect from 10PM + 1AM?

Comment: I can not. The author wants to convert varchar to time and after that do something. Conversion is done

Comment: @Sergey, you can actually, ... sum(datediff(second, '00:00:00', timeVal)). I wouldn't say you can't if just you can't sum(timeVal).

Comment: @CetinBasoz You are NOT summing **time**. You are summing a difference which is a numeric value / datatype. Don't add confusion.

Comment: @SMor, what is a time? Seconds is not 'time' unit to you, then maybe you can tell us what it is exactly.

Comment: @CetinBasoz `time` data type is a time-of-day, not a timespan. Your method doesn't sum the actual `time` value (which makes no sense, how do you add 9 o'clock to 4 o'clock?), it sums the difference from midnight. It works, it's just not the same thing

Comment: @Charlieface, I don't understand what you don't understand. 9:00:00 is 9 * 3600 seconds, no? 4:00:00 is 4 * 3600 seconds. In simple math it is (4+9) * 3600 seconds or 46800 seconds. And what should be the "same" thing? What is the meaning of "same" here? BTW why do you think it as add 9 o'clock to 4 o'clock? Instead think of it as a ToString() value of a TimeSpan. Even if it was from clock to clock, you would apply a direct datediff to get elapsed time in units you like.

Comment: @CetinBasoz No 9 o'clock is the time on my watch, as is 4 o'clock. It's like saying: what's 5th Feb + 16 June, it's simply a nonsense question. Why would you start calculating from midnight, maybe you want to start from sunrise, or the employee shift time, or the beginning of the hour? A time of day is a *single point*, and is not summable, any more than "London + Paris" is summable. If you define the question by saying: I want to sum the time from midnight, that's different. Here, OP is asking to convert values which represent *timespans* to `time` datatype, which I said wasn't ideal....

Comment: @CetinBasoz ... It works, sort-of, if you want to use it for parsing, and will then sum using `DATEDIFF`, but it's not what OP thinks it is.

Comment: @Charlieface, you are just making it complex. Why can't you think that you might have a series of varchar values in 'hh:mm:ss' format as the time elapsed in some tests for example, and you want to know the total time elapsed. Can't you really calculate it? Do you really think it is like add 5th Feb + 16 June which is totally irrelevant example? A time in SQL server is a value specifying time of day, in terms of Hour:Minute:Second. IOW 09:00:00 time value is 9 * 3600 seconds from midnight certainly and not from say sunrise, dawn etc. Well for computers time is actually a number.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Of course you can. What I'm saying is that `time` is technically the wrong data type for that. Yes, you can use it as an intermediate parsing mechanism (and that's probably even a good idea) but fundamentally it's not designed to store timespans. So OP wants the data "converted to `time` to allow summing" and I'm saying that won't help much. Ultimately, you're right that the ultimate goal is to sum these timespans, but OP's question said "convert to time", and that is not really OP's end goal. The best data type is probably `int` or `numeric` storing seconds, not `time`

Comment: OK let's say the best data type is int, which I agree, that might be expressing seconds, minutes ... how much precision is targeted. How would you go there from an string in 'hh:mm:ss' format, using time, datetime ... no? That is what I was trying to say. If you convert to time, then at least you can convert it to seconds as both denote a point of time in a day (time of day).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those values to time and for summing you could simply get their difference in seconds from midnight and sum. Result would be in seconds. ie:

```
DECLARE @times TABLE(t TIME(0));
INSERT INTO @times(t)VALUES('03:20:30'), ('02:10'), ('01:00');

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', t))FROM @times AS t;
```